# Pseudo-code answers only

Tags: discussion

I recently stumbled upon a user who knows things about [image-processing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/image-processing), but seems to be answering in pseudo-code only., i.e.
[Dilate an image based on a distribution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34319010/dilate-an-image-based-on-a-distribution/34323837#34323837) and [Lung segmentation in Matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32487572/lung-segmentation-in-matlab/32496420#32496420) . Now, these questions might be considered "too broad" to be answered with a definite code example, but is

- a pseudo-code answer acceptable in this case (I'd say close as too broad)
- posting pseudo-code only as answers considered good SO behaviour, even on questions that are not too broad?

Comment: If the pseudo-code works, why not? Often, though, it doesn't, when it becomes useless noise defended as "well, it's just pseudo-code". So, it depends...

Comment: Obligatory: https://xkcd.com/149/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no general case answer.  If the pseudocode is able to provide the important/relevant information needed to answer the question, then that's great.  If it doesn't, then it doesn't.  In the general case there's really no more to say.

If you feel that a specific question needs the actual code to really answer it (say, because it's a question about some specific language syntax) then a pseudocode answer may not be useful, vote accordingly.

If a different question isn't about the language, but rather than algorithm, and the specifics of the language used in the OP aren't relevant to the core of the question, then the answer (if it's otherwise correct, clear, etc.) is helpful, and you should vote accordingly.

Of course the nature of pseudocode is that you omit certain details of how you would go about performing certain types of operations.  If, in context, it could be assumed that the reader of the question would know how to perform those operations, then there's no need for the question to contain them, if it's likely that the reader wouldn't know the details that the pseudocode is glossing over, then it's a problem.  This is of course a judgement call, as is so often the case with voting.

Comment: Good insight, thanks. I have thus far refrained from voting, as I know not enough about image processing to determine whether his pseudo-code would work or not. Another problem I see with pseudo-code is that the OP might as well get back to SO having difficulties implementing the pc, whilst a working code example would prevent that follow-up question.