# Is posting pseudo-code in questions allowed on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, questions

If posting pseudocode is allowed, are there any particular stipulations? For example, in my post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43833726/creating-an-interface-with-an-array-of-variable-length-containing-objects-in-ty), I created some pseudocode which I felt better suited to explaining the problem than posting my own code and error message, which it appeared to me would be misleading or would obscure my real purpose (people might focus on the various syntactical problems and the error message itself, when the real problem is/was conceptualisation of certain data structures within the particular language and framework).

Furthermore it seems this particular approach was communicative enough to spawn a useful, and potentially problem solving, answer with less than a minute (!), whereas previous questions where I have included large sections of relevant or seemingly relevant code have not.

**My question is**: when and under what circumstances is posting pseudo-code in a question acceptable, if at all?

Related: this [meta question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/312642/pseudo-code-answers-only) is similar, but it appears to address pseudo-code answers, not questions.

Comment: I HATE Pseudocode `if( condition that check something ) { write the code for me plz } else { ... }`

Comment: @AlonEitan Thanks Alon, your opinion is noted. Have you had time to read the question yet?

Comment: I did, but what I'm saying is that Pseudocode in a question makes it too broad and excuse for a real MCVE, and answering  using it is not as helpful like a real code that demonstrate the solution. Of Course it might be helpful sometimes, but usually it doesn't (Where I see it being used on SO)

Comment: I agree in the majority of cases, but here I have a code-base that is complex and interconnected and not especially suited to the SO one page solution. I want to understand interfaces fully, as it's important for me for my work. I don't know how other people feel but it seems that it might be quite a common problem for people moving from old-school JS to TypeScript and other more modern JS versions and derivatives.

Comment: Well I guess that if you use it moderately then it's alright, just as Servy wrote in his answer: _"If the pseudocode is able to provide the important/relevant information needed to answer the question, then that's great"_ My comment was about people abusing it and writing it as an _afterthought_ instead of providing a real example. It suggest (To me at least) that they didn't actually tried anything. I'm not sure it's the same in your case

Comment: Also JBNizet wrote in the comments: _"When you ask about an error caused by some code, post that real code, and post that error."_ I think that's why I don't like seeing Pseudocode in questions (But I don't know if they wrote that comment because you were using Pseudocode, I can't speak on their behalf)

Comment: The question wasn't really about the error message, though I suppose the fact he misunderstood indicates some degree of fault on both sides.

Comment: I think it just boils down to: Will this pseudo-code also produce the error/problem? If yes you should be fine else use actual code.

Comment: In your particular case, you're asking about particular error thrown by existing code. If existing code is too complex or large to put into the question (a common case), you need to write specialized code (not pseudo-code) that reproduces the problem. Providing pseudo-code puts that burden on the answerer, and who'd want that? As a side benefit, writing the MVCE often clarifies the problem in your own mind, and you end up answering your own question.

Comment: @Arkadiy "In your particular case, you're asking about particular error thrown by existing code." would you mind pointing me to the part of the post that asks a question about a particular error thrown by existing code?  It must be just me, but I can't seem to find it anywhere.

Comment: @TinyGiant Oops. So much typing for bad reasons. You're right, the question is " I can't find the correct syntax for this." - not an error. I stand corrected. The question can do with a bit of editing, and I can do with a bit better reading skills.

Comment: If pseudocode is part or all of a good answer to the question, why is it _ipso facto_ bad? How often that happens for particular languages is a practical question and if for some kinds of software the answer is rarely or even never, so be it. I can imagine good answers for software I know in which pseudocode as a part of an answer is fine.

Comment: The question may not be about the error message per se, but it is about *syntax*, which is *definitely* language-specific and therefore not amenable to pseudocode. It may be appropriate to provide *both* pseudocode *and* your attempt at real code (which gives the various errors), though.

Comment: In general, I might think that if pseudo code is good to answer a question, that question belongs on software engineering stack exchange, not stack overflow.

Comment: I’m surprised that the question needs to be asked. Apart from trying to diagnosed specific errors, it should be valid to ask a question about how to go about solving a problem. Even if the language is specific, it often useful to post pseudo-pseudo code: code which is mostly normal, but with some placeholder expressions.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

> when and under what circumstances is posting pseudo-code in a question acceptable, if at all?

Can your question be minimally and completely expressed using only pseudo-code? Can it be [adequately answered using only pseudo-code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/312642/pseudo-code-answers-only)? If the answer to both of those questions is "yes", then there is no problem using pseudo-code for your question.

There is no reason to arbitrarily impose a specific language requirement on a question that does not inherently have a language requirement. Stack Overflow's charter is *"to build a library of detailed answers to every question about programming"*. Nothing about that restricts questions only to those that are expressed using some specific programming language.

In addition, it is of course fine to use pseudo-code to *elaborate* on a question. Even if there's a need to provide code in a real programming language, pseudo-code can in some cases illuminate the question in ways that the code alone may not, or at least may not as clearly. If the question would be fine *without* the pseudo-code that's included, then the inclusion of pseudo-code obviously does not in and of itself harm the question.

Which is not to say that pseudo-code is always sufficient. It's up to you as the questioner to make sure your question otherwise [meets the standards for the site](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking). Many questions that rely heavily or solely on pseudo-code do not. So, make sure that if your question is poorly received, you are not confusing complaints about the use of pseudo-code with complaints about the content itself, where the use of pseudo-code is just a symptom of a bigger problem. See related discussions in e.g. [What's the appropriate new/current close reason for “How do I do X?”](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253069) and [Why is this question *unclear* instead of *too broad*?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/319214) (these are not about pseudo-code per se, but do include discussion of the effect pseudo-code has on the quality of a question).

So, what about your specific question? You seem to summarize your question thus:

> I've had a look through the TypeScript and Angular documentation and done a few searches and I can't find the correct syntax for this

Pseudo-code and syntax are mutually exclusive. Syntax describes the *exact* structure of the code. It's meaningless without the context of a known grammar. Pseudo-code by definition has no defined grammar, and beyond that your question appears to be asking in the context of the language TypeScript. As such, your pseudo-code doesn't inform readers in any way about your attempts to solve your problem, nor to help readers understand what your specific difficulty might be.

As such, the question comes across as not showing evidence of research (which should garner down-votes), and as being too broad (which should garner close-votes). At the very least, it's not at all clear what value it is you were hoping the pseudo-code would add to the question. A real TypeScript code example, even one that doesn't compile, would have been far more useful.

Comment: I am impressed with this answer. It gets to the heart of the problems with the question that have not elsewhere been fully identified while also addressing its strengths. I have learned more from this answer than the others.

Answer (score 30):

I'm guessing that in some cases pseudo-code would be all right, such as when it's not an error-diagnosing question. If you *know* that some part is irrelevant to the main issue, but you need to give the idea what happens in some other place in code. An example would be - a well-posed architectural concern, or some framework/3rdparty library usage question. Note that in this scenario the question must be formulated very carefully, so it will be obvious that the code being pseudo-code is *really* irrelevant. In the original version of your question, this wasn't really that obvious.

Posting pseudo-code is counter-productive when asking about an error. In such case, your best course of action is to put some effort into minimizing the code sample ([MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)), so it would be free of distractions you've mentioned in your meta-question, but still will allow others to reproduce the problem easily.

If you write some pseudo-code, you only *assume* it contains the problem, but you may have as well hidden it during the transformation process in your head.

Comment: **The author is not asking about an error.** It is a how-to question. It is **not** a debugging question. They are asking how to perform a task while giving pseudo code as an example to show what they mean. This question is perfectly fine as it is and does not need to be made into a debugging question to be on-topic. The real problem with this question is that they even mentioned they attempted something and that there was an error with what they attempted. _That_ is irrelevant information.

Comment: @TinyGiant The first sentence when a problem is mentioned reads: "The interface I've tried at the moment doesn't work at all and just throws errors", so it's not that obvious as you say it is.

Comment: It's not asking about the error though. It is asking how to perform the task. It _mentions_ an error, which is completely irrelevant to the question and I have just removed.

Comment: @TinyGiant TBH I'm not sure what's it asking about ("it throws error so I've written some pseudo-code" - ???), but "asking how to perform a task" and then writing about errors being thrown is a typical formulation of a diagnosing question. Anyway, you may be right, so I've reformulated the answer to be more generic.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143742/discussion-on-answer-by-bartoszkp-is-posting-pseudo-code-in-questions-allowed-on).

Answer (score 21):

Showing real code is useful.  First, it shows an actual attempted solution.  Second, it gives people helping something to start with.

A description of what you want, when you don't know how to do it, almost always contains ambiguities.  The same is true of code you attempted to solve the problem with, and failed, but the ambiguities *tend to be different*.

Both a description of what you are trying to do, and [MCVE] attempt, plus any and all errors and warnings *verbatim*, is almost always useful.

There are exceptions, but "the problem is too big" is not one of them.  If a problem remains too big, then it may not be suitable for a StackOverflow question.

If you want to avoid downvotes, aim for a gold standard question.

Note that the question you ask *isn't just for you*.  The actual code may contain keywords that someone else will try and google.  The error message will certainly contain error codes that someone else will get and google.  The error codes themselves may pop up a "have you tried these questions to find an answer" sidebar as you are asking the question.

Sure, people could focus on your error message.  But your text must make clear what your goal is; if they fix that error message and don't reach your goal, then their answer is poor.

There could be a case where posting pseudo-code is a good idea.  But it is going to be an extremely small use case.  Almost always posting code as real as you can get it clarifies communication.  Pseudo-code tends to only be useful **when you are trying to communicate in a situation where you fully understand what matters**, and when you are asking *other people* for help obviously you do not fully understand the situation.

Real code can communicate the same things pseudo-code can, except whole swaths of ambiguity and confusion are eliminated in making it (mostly) compile and be as valid as you can be.

Pseudo code is permitted, but it rarely makes a question better, and often makes it worse.  Downvoting is just as permitted.

Pseudo-code doesn't always mean "question should be closed", it just *usually* does, and your question (if not otherwise amazing) may be closed by over zealous people and/or people who don't fully understand it.

Answer (score 16):

Posting pseudocode is fine if you're trying to figure out how to solve a problem and can't solve it directly (i.e., you don't know the way you would do (whatever thing) in (whatever language)) but want to explain approximately the solution you'd like to come up with.  Even then you should post as much actual code as is feasible - at least a starting dataset/starting point/etc. (depending on what you're asking) and desired ending point.  If it's necessary to explain the in-between in pseudocode, fine, but don't consider it a replacement for *actual* code, more of a replacement for actual *english*.

It's not acceptable for help debugging an error.  An [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) though might be exactly what you're trying to really say: something that is not *your* production code (which may well be actually illegal/unethical to post), but *actual runnable code* that *reproduces your error*, in as simple a fashion as possible.

Nothing is more frustrating as an answer-er than to see someone post "when I run my code, which does XYZ, I get an error".  Especially when they don't say the error message verbatim - but even if they do, it's still extremely frustrating to not see *the actual code*, because without that it's impossible to rule out things like missing/extra semicolons, typos, mistaken brackets, etc., which is a key step (the first one, usually) in debugging.

Moreover, though, it also means that unless I happen to know off the top of my head what causes the issue - likely because I've run into the error before - I'll have to construct my *own* MVCE.  And even if I *do* know the likely answer, I'll still want to construct an MVCE in order to test whether I'm right.

So - no, please don't use pseudocode unless you're asking an *algorithm* type question.

Comment: I was surprised that your answer is the first one to mention "algorithm". I think for an algorithm question, like complexity or optimization of an existing algorithm, pseudo-code can even be better than real code: It will help you to focus on the actual algorithm steps, leaving out all language (and compiler, operating system, etc.) specific optimizations.

Comment: @erg I was too...

Answer (score 6):

The main problem with pseudo-code in a question is it can often obscure the real problem that. If you can be 100% sure that you are not doing so- one such case can be when, like you mention, the question is really a conceptual one, then  I don't see any problem as such.

Answer (score 2):

Pseudocode can be an effective way of communicating requirements. If the question is of the form "How do I write a program/function in language L that does X", then using pseudo-code to express "X" might well be appropriate. The danger of course is that it relies on the author and the reader having the same shared understanding of the semantics of the pseudo-code; it thus gives an appearance of formality which may be entirely illusary.

Comment: *"How do I write a program/function in language L that does X"* is bad example for pseudo-code question. They are downvoted for lack of research most of time, even without pseudo-code.

Answer (score 0):

> This answer is regarding the specific example in the question.

Because you are not asking a debugging question, **you are not required to include any code at all** (only debugging style questions explicitly require code). Including code *can*—in some cases—help narrow down your how-to style questions. Including pseudo code for how-to style questions when you are having trouble communicating what you're trying to achieve can—in some cases—be extremely helpful.

Your question mentioned that you had attempted to solve the problem but your attempts only resulted in errors. **This is not relevant to your how-to question**. Unless you're going to include the attempt and the errors you encountered (effectively making the how-to question into a debugging question), you should just exclude that information. It will only serve to derail the question as has happened here. People will want to see your (irrelevant) failed attempt and the error(s) that it produced, which is counter to your actual goal.